# Calling constructor of a template base class from a template derived class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am porting some code from Visual Studio to Mingw GCC. This code runs fine on visual studio however when I attempt to build it in Mingw I get the following issues. The code is given below

```
HeaderFile
template <MThread Thread>
class AFWork : public EffectFramework<Thread>
{
public:
    AFWork(HINSTANCE hinst, HWND hWindow,
                       const std::wstring& stSharedDataPath,
                       const std::wstring& stGameDataPath,
                       const std::wstring& stExtendedGameDataPath,
                       int nScrWidth, int nScrHeight);
    virtual ~AFWork(void);
    ...
    ...
};
```

The other header file of the base class that is referenced above is:

```
HeaderFile
template <MThread Thread>
class EffectFramework : public ktWin32Framework
{   
public:
    typedef boost::function<void (int window_no, HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)> WindowProcedure;

    EffectFramework<Thread>( std::wstring& name,
                             std::wstring& dataDirPrefix,
                             VSYNC vsync,
                             HINSTANCE hinst, 
                             HINSTANCE hprevinst, 
                             LPSTR args, 
                             int mode,
                             IApplicationManager* appl_manager = NULL);
    ....
    ....
};
```

Implimentation of the constructor of derived class

```
                    template <MThread Thread>
                    AFWork<Thread>::AFWork(HINSTANCE hinst,
                                           HWND hWindow,
                                           const std::wstring& stSharedDataPath,
                                           const std::wstring& stGameDataPath,
                                           const std::wstring& stExtendedDataPath,
                                           int nScrWidth,
                                           int nScrHeight)

:  EffectFramework<Thread>::EffectFramework(wstring(L"ArtViewer"), wstring(L""), VSYNC::VSYNC_1, hinst, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL) <---ERROR
{
}
```

The error that I get is this

```
error: no matching function for call to 'T_Wrapper::EffectFramework<(T_Wrapper::T_Thread)0u>::EffectFramework(std::wstring, std::wstring, T_Wrapper::VSYNC, HINSTANCE__*&, int, int, int, int)'|
```

Any suggestions on why I am getting this error and how I can resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that the candidate constructor from `EffectFramework` has `std::wstring&` as the first and second parameters, but you are passing temporary variables. If you would pass, for example, global variables, then it should work.